# MarkLogic 8 JavaScript Arrays

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm trying to work with arrays. This is some working code that explains what I am doing.

```
// query

var a = ["1000", "2000", "3000"];
var b = ["2000"];    

for (i in b) {
  var index = a.indexOf(b[i]);
};

if (index > -1) {
    a.splice(index, 1);
};

a
```

Now when I use this same logic for my query results, it does not work anymore.

```
// query

queryDo = cts.andQuery([
      cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("displayable", "true"),
      cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("section", "dikw Track Events"),
      cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("name", 'dikw_default'),
      cts.collectionQuery(["reference/application"])
    ]);

queryDont = cts.andQuery([
      cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("displayable", "false"),
      cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("section", "dikw Track Events"),
      cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("name", 'Helpdesk'),
      cts.collectionQuery(["reference/application"])
    ]);

var qDo = cts.jsonPropertyWords("code", null, "document", queryDo).toArray();
var qDont = cts.jsonPropertyWords("code", null, "document", queryDont).toArray();

for (i in qDont) {
  var index = qDo.indexOf(qDont[i]);
};

if (index > -1) {
    qDo.splice(index, 1);
};

qDo
```

I've verified that the result of both queries is an array. The arrays consist of values just like the example code; 1000, 2000, etc.
Also, when I use a notAndQuery to exclude results from the 2nd query from the first, this has no effect.

When I look at qDo[2] for example, the right value is returned.

**My andNotQuery:**

```
queryDo = cts.andQuery([
      cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("displayable", "true"),
      cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("section", "dikw Track Events"),
      cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("name", 'dikw_default'),
      cts.collectionQuery(["reference/application"])
    ]);

queryDont = cts.andQuery([
      cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("displayable", "false"),
      cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("section", "dikw Track Events"),
      cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("name", 'Helpdesk'),
      cts.collectionQuery(["reference/application"])
    ]);

andnot = cts.andNotQuery(queryDo, queryDont);

result = cts.jsonPropertyWords("code", null, "document", andnot);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After filing a bug at MarkLogic I got this repsonse from the engineering team:

> "The return from the lexicon call is a `StringWithFrequency` (not just a
>   String) so the JS layer wraps it"

You can create an Array from the call to `cts.jsonPropertyWords` as you did before, but you'll need to iterate through and get the string values for each item in turn first. Something like this:

1. Create the Array from `cts.jsonPropertyWords` as before
2. Create a new Array
3. Iterate through the original Array and push each items's string value into the new Array. The call to `indexOf` will work on the new Array.

**Work around**

```
var trackCodes = cts.jsonPropertyWords("code", null, "document", cts.andQuery([])).toArray();
var tc2 = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < trackCodes.length; i++){
  tc2.push(trackCodes[i].toString())
}

tc2.indexOf(["your value"])
```

Answer (score 3):

The for/in operator may not be iterating over the array in the way you expect:

"There is no guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are inherited."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

In addition, for/in may inhibit optimization in v8:

https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#5-for-in

If you use the familiar `for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {...}` statement, does that produce the expected results?

Hoping that helps,

Comment: I also ran into this problem and using classical for loop worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a flaw in your logic. The if at the end seems misplaced. If you extend your example with the number to include another value, it goes wrong:

```
var a = ["1000", "2000", "3000", "4000"];
var b = ["2000", "3000"];    

for (i in b) {
  var index = a.indexOf(b[i]);
};

if (index > -1) {
    a.splice(index, 1);
};

a
```

Instead, the if should be within the for loop:

```
var a = ["1000", "2000", "3000", "4000"];
var b = ["2000", "3000"];    

for (i in b) {
  var index = a.indexOf(b[i]);

  if (index > -1) {
      a.splice(index, 1);
  };
};

a
```

But it could be worthwhile to explore using a notQuery in some way. Depending on the layout of your data, that could work. That would be much more efficient as well, as you wouldn't have to do custom filtering after the searches.

HTH!

Comment: I've change my code to reflect your change for the loop on array b. Also included my andNotQuery.

Comment: I think your andNot query needs to be more selective. You have a collection query in both queryDo and queryDont. So with the andNotQuery you get `collection ref/app and not collection ref/app`.. :)

Comment: the difference is on this line: 
    cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("name", 'Helpdesk')
I have tested the queries en 1 returns 1000, 2000, 3000 and the other returns 2000. The result using andNot is still the entire first sequence.